# Https connection fails through POSTMAN

Tags: node.js, ssl, certificate, postman

I'm running nodejs app using node13.1.

When access hit the end point using POSTMAN, I get the following error:

"Error: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established"

[POSTMAN Console Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3G6e8.png)

Can anyone help?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is not related to Node.js, maybe you missed something.
Did you disable `SSL Certificate Validation` in settings?

Comment: I don't want to disable it. I want my self-signed certificate to work with https request

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this issue? I am facing the same.